# Excel-VBA: Variable declaration necessary?

Tags: vba, excel, variable-declaration

Would it be wrong if write the following code

```
Sub Something()
 Dim i As integer
 Dim xRange As Range
 Dim yRange As Range

 Set xRange= Range("x_table")
 Set yRange= Range("y_table")

 For i = 1 To xRange.Columns.Count
    xRange.Columns(i) = Application.Sum(y_table.Columns(i))
 Next i
End Sub
```

without specifically declaring each of the variables? Like bellow;

```
Sub Something()
 Set xRange= Range("x_table")
 Set yRange= Range("y_table")

 For i = 1 To xRange.Columns.Count
    xRange.Columns(i) = Application.Sum(y_table.Columns(i))
 Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If Option Explicit isn't turned on you *can* do it that way, but I wouldn't recommend it because then you're relying on the framework to guess at the type of variable it is dealing with, which could cause unexpected results.

Comment: @DaMartyr, thanks! if you will be a uni professor, will you mark me down for not declaring?

Comment: start typing "xrange." and watch the methods and properties expanding on the dot in your 1st example while it does not in your 2nd example - this will give you help and confidence when you code - that's why I always qualify my objects first. There is hardly any case where you must use late binding

Comment: @MikeD, that is true, i also declare them to write the program but then i delete them once i finish, it just makes a 3 line `sub` become a cake of code

Comment: Yep. It is a bad practice. In medium/large projects you may enter deep waters without Option Explicit.

Comment: @belisarius, then, is there a shortcut to initializing variables in VBA. Something like in java `int  i, j, k`?

Comment: @Carlos  Dim i, j, k As Integer ... logicamente

Comment: @belisarius--no, No, NO, a thousand times NO! That's one of the traps of VB-based languages (VB & VBA). "Dim i, j, k As Integer" will get you ONE integer (k) and two Variants (i & j). You can do it all on one line, thus: "Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer"

Comment: the two code blocks behave different: in (1) "i" is and remains an Integer, in case 2 "i" is Variant/Empty in the beginning, and changes to Variant/Long on implicit initialisation at the For statement. Being a Long it has a different range and occupies more space - it will maybe hide overflows or accidental assignment of wrong Vartypes (like String) you would like to detect at developing time before s..t happens during live operation. This is particularly important when you use such var's as parameters to call functions/subs.

Comment: try to set i="x" in both examples: in (1) you get a "Type mismatch" right on the spot where s..t happens; in (2) you get an error only at the Next statement. In a large program with nested Subs, Functions and Classes it can take you ages to find the root cause.

Answer (score 7):

It works fine, until it doesn't.

Your examples are pretty simple, but its entirely possible to come up with situations that cause problems.

Better to declare all so that you don't risk running into ambiguity at runtime.

I'm also partial to MikeD's comment regarding autocomplete.